# Having Trouble with Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard

Hi Everyone iam new to Android and stuck in really silly problem in my project i have one EditText which is defined in Header View of a List View whenever users touches the EditText soft keyboard will be displayed. i have something called clear button which clears the EditText After clearing soft keyboard is not displaying in 2.3 devices.Whenever i press lock/power button lock the device and unlock then soft keyboard is displaying

```
<activity
        android:name=".pl.Mobile.AddJobNew"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
         >
```

Here is My Activity Declaration in Android for android:windowSoftInputMode :   'adjustResize' option working perfectly for Android 2.3 devices but failed in 4.0 devices where soft keyboard overlapping over edit text . option 'adjustPan' is workin good in 4.0 devices but failed in 2.3 devices

Please help me get out of this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Remove request focus from your Edit Text if your Edit Text have it

Comment: @SoftwareSainath - If my solution has worked for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in the activity with the edit text:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
// Do something for 4.0 and above versions
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
} 
else{
// do something for phones running an SDK before 4.0
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
}
```

Also remove,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

From your activity in the manifest file.

[Build.Version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that when you click the clear button, the editText looses its focus so the keyboard hides itself.

I would try 2 things to solve it;

1. after you clean the text, do:

   yourEditTextField.requestFocus()
2. manually control the keyboard visibility:

   public void showKeyboard(){
       View view = getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
       if (view==null)
           return;

   ```
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
   ```

   }

   public void hideKeyboard(){
       View view = getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
       if (view==null)
           return;

   ```
   IBinder binder = view.getWindowToken();
   if (binder == null)
       return;

    // prevent a bug in some keyboards that makes the text hang on the screen
   if (view instanceof EditText) 
       ((EditText)view).setText(((EditText)view).getText().toString());


   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binder, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

I have below line in My AndroidManifest.xml file and it works great. Please try this code. Dont put any extra code. And still if you not get  any success then let me know. I will like to help you out.

```
<activity android:name=".pl.Mobile.AddJobNew" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Try with above code for your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that

```
    editext1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
            {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    if (v instanceof EditText)
                    {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        v.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

If it not work for you try to add

```
        editext1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
        {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });
```

Also is good to remove request focus from layout. and maybe set this **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateAlwaysHidden"** in manifest on activity