# Android Close/Hide keyboard programmatically in TabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-softkeyboard

I am currently working on an Android application and when you first load up this application it uses TabHost to display the various views (activities) of the application. So when it loads up it has a view where the user can enter a number so the softkeyboard is automatically shown.

At first I presumed when the user went to the other Tabs in the application if there was not EditText fields the keyboard would dissapear, however the keyboard remains and switches from a number pad to the standard text keyboard and the only way to close it is by clicking the back button on the device. This is not user friendly and not what I want as when the user switches to another tab the keyboard should close.

I have created the code below which should have closed the keyboard if it is currently open on the screen.

```
private OnTabChangeListener MyOnTabChangeListener = new OnTabChangeListener(){
        @Override

            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the Tab Changed Function!!");
                if(getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("SecondTab")) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the SecondTab Section!!");

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    if(imm != null)
                    { 
                        Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the SecondTab imm null!!");
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0); 
                    }

                }
                if(getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("FirstTab")) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the FirstTab Section!!");


                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    if(imm != null)
                    { 
                        Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the FirstTab imm null!!");
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT); 
                    } 

                }
            }


    };
```

This code above does work as if I go to the second tab and the keyboard is open on the first tab it will be closed, however if I then go to say the third tab and then back to the second tab it re-opens the keyboard which I dont want, as I only need the keyboard on the first tab.

Can anyone please help me with this as I cant believe its so hard just to control the soft keyboard.

Thanks in advance

EDIT....

I have even tried using the code below within the SecondTab click listener with no luck:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    if(imm != null)
                    { 
                        Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the SecondTab imm null!!");
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); 
                    }
```

EDIT 2.....

I appreciate the first response below however I have tried adding that to the activity itself but for some reason it does not work :S I have also tried a number of different thing with no luck I even added the below to my manifest file but this didn't work which is puzzling :s

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

That should have worked but didn't which is really annoying. Part of my manifest file is below:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TabActivityTop"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Tab1" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Tab2" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Tab3" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Tab4" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
    </application>
```

I have also included my full TabActivityTop.java file below if that helps:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TabActivityTop extends TabActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabSpec tab1spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
        tab1spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_tab1_tab));
        Intent tab1Intent = new Intent(this, tab1.class);
        tab1spec.setContent(tab1Intent);

        TabSpec tab2spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("");
        tab2spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_tab2_tab));
        Intent tab2Intent = new Intent(this, tab2.class);
        tab2spec.setContent(tab2Intent);

        TabSpec tab3spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("");
        tab3spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_tab3_tab));
        Intent tab3Intent = new Intent(this, tab3.class);
        tab3spec.setContent(tab3Intent);

        TabSpec tab4spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4");
        tab4spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_tab4_tab));
        Intent tab4Intent = new Intent(this, tab4.class);
        tab4spec.setContent(tab4Intent);

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(MyOnTabChangeListener);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);
        tabHost.addTab(tab4);
    }

    private OnTabChangeListener MyOnTabChangeListener = new OnTabChangeListener(){
        @Override

            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the Tab Changed Function!!");
                if(getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("contact")) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the Tab4 Section!!");

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
                    if(imm != null)
                    { 
                        Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the imm null!!");
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); 
                    }

                }
                if(getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("Tab1")) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "I am Inside the Tab1 Section!!");
                }
            }

    };


}
```

I really hope someone can please help me with this :)

Comment: has anyone got any ideas or can tell me where im going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357889/having-trouble-with-soft-keyboard/14489169#14489169

Comment: Hi Mertuarez, I have read the attached link but I could not play that code in the activity as it has not EditText element. The issue remains the keyboard doesn't close when the tabs are pressed. For some reason it persists, any ideas??

Comment: remove <requestFOcus/> from layouts

Comment: I dont have <requestFOcus/> on any views

Comment: its only since I started using a tabHost have I seen this issue :S

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Or try use:

```
 rootLayout.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Where would this go? on the activity or within the Tab change listener?

Comment: where you want, i think in onTabChanged()